# Can't have the status of a post request in my front-end

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, spring-boot, angular-cli

i have a spring boot controller, and i'm trying to return to my frontend(i use angular cli) the response value (200,300,400,...) of a http post request, the problem is that when the post request fails my code does not return the status error, and i can't really understand why; i need the status of the request in the front end in order to show a toastr in case of success or errors
here is my front-end code:

```
postdipendenti(raw: any,comp:any,gr:any,fp:any){
    var dip = '{'  +'"id"'+':'+'0'+','+'"nome"'+':'+'"'+raw[0]+'"'+','+'"cognome"'+':'+'"'+raw[1]+'"'+','+'"data_nascita"'+':'+'"'+raw[2]+'"'+','+'"mail"'+':'+'"'+raw[3]+'"'+','+'"telefono"'+':'+raw[4]+','+'"setCompetenze"'+':'+JSON.stringify(comp)+',"listaGr":'+JSON.stringify(gr)+',"fp":'+JSON.stringify(fp) +'}'
    const obj = JSON.parse(dip);
    console.log("non json ->"+ dip)
    var res=this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:8080/postdipendente_competenze', obj).subscribe(
        (val) => {console.log("andata "+ JSON.stringify(val))
        if(val == "200")
            this.toastr.success("dipendente inserito correttamente","SUCCESSO");
        },
        (error) => {                              //Error callback
        console.log('error caught in component '+error)
        this.toastr.error("dipendente non inserito","ERRORE")
        }
    )
    
}
```

and here is my back-end:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@PostMapping("postdipendente_competenze") // aggiunge un nuovo dipendente con competenze esistenti
public ResponseEntity<?> addDipendenteCompetenze(@RequestBody dipendenteRequest dipReq) {
    try {
        ds.addDipendenteCompetenze(dipReq);//function that does the post request
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(200);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).body(409);

    } catch (BadRequest e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(400);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(500);
    }

}
```

what am i doing wrong? i'm stuck and i can't understand why. any help is welcome, thanks.

Comment: What is the response you're getting back? What do the server logs show? What shows in the network tab in the browser devtools? None of that code you posted looks unreasonable. "When the post request fails" fails how? Network error, server error, etc etc. "Doesn't work" isn't enough for us to help you.

Comment: try with @PostMapping("/postdipendente_competenze")